# Binding Knockout.JS viewmodel to jQuery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a jQuery modal dialog inside which I would like to pass data from a Knockout viewmodel. The dialog works fine as is - however, below code is broken.

Ideally, I would like to be able to click on the URI that triggers the modal dialog, and have the dialog load the data from the Knockout viewmodel. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Markup:**

```
<a href="#" id="listNames">List Names</a>

<div  id="listNames"  data-bind="dataModel: { autoOpen: false, modal: true }">
<div> 
    <form action=''>
        <p>You have added <span data-bind='text: name().length'>&nbsp;</span> 
            person(s)</p>
        <table data-bind='visible: name().length > 0'>
            <thead>
                <tr><th>Select</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th />
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind='foreach: metrics'>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
                    <td><span data-bind='text: name' >&nbsp;</span></td>
                    <td><span  data-bind='text: age'>&nbsp;</span></td> 
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
var dataModel = function (edata) {
    var self = this;
    self.edata = ko.observableArray(edata);

    self.addname = function () {
        self.edata.push({
            name: "",
            age: ""
        });
    };

    self.removename = function (name) {
        self.edata.remove(name);
    };

    self.save = function (form) {
        alert("Could now transmit to server: " 
              + ko.utils.stringifyJson(self.edata));
        // To actually transmit to server as a regular form post, write this: 
        // ko.utils.postJson($("form")[0], self.edata);
    };
};

var viewModel = new dataModel([
    { name: "Jack", age: "41" },
    { name: "Jill", age: "33" }
]);
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel);
```

**jQuery Dialog:**

```
$("#listNames, ").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 300,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "OK": function () {
            $(this).dialog("destroy");
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

$("#openList")
    .click(function () {
        $("#listNames").dialog("open");
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few errors in the code you posted.
I have a working version here : http://jsfiddle.net/uFgz8/1/

**Here is the HTML :**

```
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.openDialog"> Open dialog </a> //you had 2 elements with the same ID, I removed the ID on the link and bound it to a method in the view model

    <div id="listNames">   <div>
            <form action=''>
                <p>You have added <span data-bind='text: name.length'>&nbsp;</span> person(s)</p> // name item is not observable, so you cannot use name().length
                <table data-bind='visible: name.length > 0'> // same remark for name
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Select</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Age</th>
                            <th />
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody data-bind='foreach: edata'>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" />
                            </td>
                            <td><span data-bind='text: name'>&nbsp;</span>

                            </td>
                            <td><span data-bind='text: age'>&nbsp;</span>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**The JS:**

```
$("#listNames").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 300,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "OK": function () {
            // do something
            $(this).dialog("close"); // I replaced destroy by close, so it can be opened after ok has been clicked
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

var dataModel = function (edata) {
    var self = this;
    self.edata = ko.observableArray(edata);

    self.addname = function () {
        self.edata.push({
            name: "",
            age: ""
        });
    };

    self.openDialog = function () {
        $("#listNames").dialog("open");
    };

    self.removename = function (name) {
        self.edata.remove(name);
    };

    self.save = function (form) {
        alert("Could now transmit to server: " + ko.utils.stringifyJson(self.edata));
        // To actually transmit to server as a regular form post, write this: ko.utils.postJson($("form")[0], self.edata);
    };
};

var viewModel = new dataModel([{
    name: "Jack",
    age: "41"
}, {
    name: "Jill",
    age: "33"
}]);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel); // you have created a variable viewModel with data, but you bound ko with a new object of type viewModel, you must either call ko with viewModel you created, or inline the creation of a new "dataModel"
```

edit : I added some comments to my changes

edit 2 : I updated the link to the jsfiddle to get to the correct version ;)